# Determine sender when second form opens?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have been learning C# and WPF on a recent project of mine and I have run into an issue determining the sender when a certain form opens.  I have a main form with a listbox that is bound to a list of objects.  I used the following code to handle the user double clicking a line in the list box:

```
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
                <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="ListBoxItem_MouseDoubleClick"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Where I have run into an issue is I want to launch a second form (named "AddProject") when the user double clicks, but I also launch the same form from and button on the main form.  I need to determine which (the double click or the button click) launched the secondary form so I can change it appropriately.

In the main form, I can use the Window_loaded method, and read the sender name, but when I try to use the same in the secondary form, it doesn't work.  This works in the main form, but not the secondary:

```
   private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(sender.ToString()); 
    }
```

When the button is clicked, the following code is run to open the AddProject form:

```
   private void btnAddProject_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   { 
       AddProject frm = new AddProject();

       frm.ShowDialog();
   }
```

I know determining a sender is a common issue all over stack-overflow, but I couldn't find a good answer as to how to determine the sender which has opened a second form.  I figured I could just run it in the window_load method of the second form, but that doesn't seem to work.  Any help or a link to a discussion that does answer my question is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just to clarify, you want access to the clicked item in the second form? In other words, the `sender` variable from the first handler?

Comment: I need to identify who the sender is, either the doubleclick or the button click, so that I can then subsequently modify the form upon loading depending on which was the sender.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably you have something like this:

```
private void ListBoxItem_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    AddProject frm = new AddProject();

    frm.ShowDialog();
}
```

And of course you've explicitly stated you have this:

```
private void btnAddProject_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    AddProject frm = new AddProject();

    frm.ShowDialog();
}
```

Why can't you just change the `AddProject` class constructor, and pass an appropriate flag? Like this:

```
class AddProject
{
    private bool _fromButton;

    public AddProject(bool fromButton)
    {
        _fromButton = fromButton;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Then your methods look like this:

```
private void ListBoxItem_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    AddProject frm = new AddProject(false);

    frm.ShowDialog();
}

private void btnAddProject_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    AddProject frm = new AddProject(true);

    frm.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: I think this would work fine.  I am going to test it out...the one limitation I see is that it only covers those two options.  Checking the sender directly leaves future options more open if I find a reason to open that form with other calls.  Otherwise I would have to constantly modify the constructor to cover any new cases I uncover.  That's not unreasonable I guess.

Comment: If you anticipate the need to handle additional scenarios, then simply use an `enum` instead of the `bool` shown here. Your secondary window actually should not have dependencies on the invoker at all. I only named the variable `fromButton` for lack of a better name. But really, whether `bool` or `enum`, the `AddProject` class should use value names that reflect what it should _do_ in each scenario, rather than how it was created. E.g. the name should reflect the modifications to the form required, not why they are required.